# Can't connect to Magento Marketplace

Tags: magento2, component-manager

From System => Setup I choose "Component Manager", then when typing public and private access keys the following error shows up:

Couldn't resolve host 'repo.magento.com'

Same happens if I try to type keys from "System config"
What is wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento Marketplace has not launched yet; however, you should not be seeing that error. IOW, even though Marketplace isn't live, `repo.magento.com` is available and you should be able to use the Component Manager.

Suggest you ping `repo.magento.com` from your Magento server and do standard things that enable you to see if there is a route to that host.

It's also possible there was a transitory network issue.

Comment: Thank you. There was some trouble on my web server actually.